# videos converted to gif with ffmpeg have a box pattern background

Tags: video, youtube, ffmpeg, gif

I recently started using ffmpeg to convert small videos I make into gifs. However, I'm noticing that all gifs I make have a pattern background of some kind. It's not too noticeable of a difference between the video and the gif, but you can see it clearly in the difference between the video preview and the gif preview:

[Original video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1gaJcWlb0I)

[Gif in imgur album, along with a thumbnail of the gif and the video](https://imgur.com/a/yUhWP)

The command I send to ffmpeg to convert:

```
ffmpeg -i "video path" -pix_fmt rgb24 "output file path"
```

I've tried it with and without the -pix_fmt rgb24. Any ideas what else it could be?

Answer (score 3):

The palette filters work here, as the palettegen filter applies `Frankie Sierra dithering v2 "Lite"` by default.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -lavfi [0]split[a][b];[a]palettegen[p];[b]fifo[v];[v][p]paletteuse out.gif
```

Note that FFmpeg's GIF encoder does not support RGB24. Better to choose `pal8` since the palette is limited to 256 colors.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -lavfi [0]split[a][b];[a]palettegen[p];[b]fifo[v];[v][p]paletteuse,format=pal8 out.gif
```

Comment: You're right, couldn't get it to work (and strange). Anyways, upvoted this instead. Just be careful with Sierra Lite as it like Floyd-Steinberg distributes errors meaning you can get some weird dithering going on when animated.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks a ton! I would have never figured that out on my own haha.